# Ruby On Rails file selector

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am developing my first Ruby On Rails project and I have the following question.
Is it possible to display a window with the contents of a folder so I can select a  file? For example, images from the "app/assets/images" project folder.

I have searched in Google and rubygems.org but have not found anything.

Respectfully,
Jorge Maldonado

Answer (score 0):

You could write a controller method and associated view that scan over a folder and output the contents. Here's an example.

Controller:

```
def folder
  @files = Dir.open(Rails.root.join('public', 'images'))
end
```

View:

```
<table>
  <% @files.each do |file| %>
    <tr><td><%= link_to file, file_path(file) %></td></tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Note that `file_path` is assumed to be some route defined in `routes.rb` which accepts a file name and allows the user to view/open/download that file.

Here's a gem that also gives similar functionality:
https://github.com/furkancelik/fcfinder